# How to prevent ListView reload when it's size changed?

Tags: android

I have an activity which have a toolbar and a FrameLayout. FrameLayout is placeholder for fragments. In one of my fragments, there is my main screen ListView.

Currently, when user scrolls down in this ListView, I hide Toolbar. When user scrolls up, I show the Toolbar again.

The code looks like this so far:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollObserver(){
            @Override
            public void onScrollUp() {
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollDown() {
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        });
```

And this is OnScrollObserver:

```
public abstract class OnScrollObserver implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    public abstract void onScrollUp();

    public abstract void onScrollDown();

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    int last = 0;
    boolean control = true;

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int current, int visibles, int total) {
        if (current < last && !control) {
            onScrollUp();
            control = true;
        } else if (current > last && control) {
            onScrollDown();
            control = false;
        }

        last = current;
    }
}
```

It works so far but there is a problem. When Toolbar is hidden, ListView takes up the whole screen which is intended behavior. But the problem is when this happens, ListView is reloaded due to change in size (I assume). Everything is redrawn and recalculated which slows the performance.

Is there any alternatives to this? How to prevent reload each time Toolbar is hidden or shown?

Comment: I think ListView is not reload again , it may be different cause. Show adapter code

Comment: Adapter code is kinda long. It is a BaseAdapter using viewholder pattern. You have any idea what could be an issue in adapter?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use below code instead of yours :

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollObserver(){
@Override
public void onScrollUp() {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

@Override
public void onScrollDown() {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }

        });
```

Comment: The point of hiding the toolbar is gaining more space. When I do it invisible it just turns into a white empty area which does nothing.

Comment: Okay, this was solution for prevent to resize your listview.
Do you want to show full screen listview then it will be resize.

Comment: Yes when scrolled, ListView will be fullscreen and Toolbar is hidden.

Comment: please refer this link : https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/

Comment: There is one more link which would be help you it is as below :

http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/09/android-showhide-actionbar-when.html